# How to take user back to First Tab in TabBarcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, tabbarcontroller

I am using a Tabbarcontroller in my application. I have added a tabbarcontroller as a root view to deleagate, also there are 5 tabs in it. Now the problem come I have added a logout button on delegate window it show on top of all view to the right hand side of navigation bar.
I used a logout button so that user can logout from any tabs and go back to the first tab of tabBar controller but it doesn't happen to me. Can any one suggest me how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[yourTabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]
```

or

```
[tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `selectedViewController` property of your `UITabBarController`.  The documentation says:

> "you can use this property to select any of the view controllers in the
>   viewControllers property"

You could, for example, create a category on `UITabBarController` with a method such as:

```
- (void)selectFirstController {
    self.selectedViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}
```